# Node Js Debugger address already in use

Tags: node.js, express, vscode-debugger

I'm a beginner in learning Node Js and I'm trying to debug but I'm getting this error:

```
Waiting for the dError: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1300:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1348:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1436:7)
    at Function.listen (c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Node\online-shop\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Node\online-shop\app.js:26:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:953:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1327:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
ebugger to disconnect...
```

I've tried PORT 3001 and others but I'm still getting the same error

Here's my launch.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my app.js file

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: I believe the debugger will start your program with debugger attached. Try only pressing `F5` **without** `node app.js` in a separate terminal.

Comment: yeah, there's where I had a problem. I was running nodemon and the debugger at the same time, So the port was already being used. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop Running app by using `npm start` or `yarn start` and try again to debug. You can not run application and debug both at the same time. Node Debugger will run the application into the port you specified.